# python pexepect new line

Tags: python, newline, pexpect

I am super new to python and i have a simple question
I have this function

```
def testU(self):
        b = pexpect.spawn('users')
        b.expect('root user2')
```

and it works fine..
and this function

```
def testW(self):
    b = pexpect.spawn('whoami')
    b.expect('root')
```

and it is also fine.

but when i try to have both of them together, i get an error, I think it is because of the way i wrote the new line

```
def testZ(self):
    b = pexpect.spawn('whoami; users')
    b.expect('root\nroot user2')
```

so, how should i represent the newline in my string?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not put two commands in a single spawn. You can use a trick:

```
b = pexpect.spawn("bash -c 'whoami;users'")
```

To match newlines, you should use:

```
b.expect('root\r\nroot user2')
```

Terminal TTY device drivers (dumb, vt100, ANSI, xterm, etc.) all use the CR/LF combination to mark the end of line. UNIX uses just linefeeds to end lines in files, but not when it comes to TTY devices.

You can read more about it from [here](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Find_the_end_of_line_--_CR.2FLF_conventions).

Comment: it seems it works now, but it does not accept having two functions in spawn: i get this error: 'ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: whoami;.'
do you know how to put 2 commands?

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to update this in my answer. You can not put two commands in a spawn. But you can do a trick. See my updated answer. @user1763553